# Corrupted video (Green/pink) on Premiere Pro CS6 in Win8.1 Pro 64bit but not on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: video, premiere, windows, mac

I have a volume license for Premier Pro CS6 whereby I can run it on Mac OS and Windows.

When I run it on Windows, I get this:

[image]

But on MacOS it is fine.

The video is HDV 1440x1080i MPEG4 QuickTime.

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: I'd examine your codecs. There are utilities that will tell you what codec is actually being used. Does this happen if you play a 1440x1080 QT video outside of Premiere?

Comment: It plays OK on MPC-HC (Media Player Classic) for Windows, Jim. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: FWIW, that green/pink combination is often an indication of Y'CbCr data being interpreted as RGB.

Answer (score 0):

You can change 
Disable GPU acceleration of effects

1. Choose Project > Project Settings > General.
2. In the Video Rendering And Playback section, select the appropriate renderer: Mercury Playback Engine GPU Acceleration or Mercury Playback Engine Software Only.

It Worked For Me